# How to change the root when deploying a Typescript cloudfunction from a monorepo with cloud build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a monorepo where one of the folders has Typescript cloud functions I want to deploy using GCP cloud build. However it looks like cloud build can't understand where package.json is. I assume it is looking for it in the root folder. What would be the best way to deploy this?

Structure:

```
repo
  - app2
  - functions
    - cloudbuild.yaml
    - src
      - index.ts
      - onNewPostComment
         - index.ts
      - function2...
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

My cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'run','build']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  id: 'deploy-onNewPostComment'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - onNewPostComment
  - --region=europe-west2
  - --source=.
  - --entry-point=onNewPostComment
  - --trigger-http
  - --runtime=nodejs16
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions",
    ...,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  ...
  "private": true
}
```

Output of GCP cloud build for npm install:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
npm WARN workspace No description
npm WARN workspace No repository field.
npm WARN workspace No README data
npm WARN workspace No license field.

up to date in 0.293s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Output for npm build:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /workspace/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-27T09_05_46_164Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [link](https://www.ashsmith.io/improved-mono-repo-for-typescript-cloud-function-development) :

**Initial repo structure:**

First up, we'll need to setup our initial repo structure like so:

```
docker/
  functions/
    Dockerfile
    start.sh
src/
  functions/
    http/
      helloWorld/
        index.ts
        index.test.ts
        package.json
  packages/
    lib/
      index.ts
      package.json
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
docker-compose.yml
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

As mentioned in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64069554/15774176) :

> When you run a Cloud Build job, it copies all the files from the
> current directory. If you are in a subdirectory, all the sibling or
> parents directory aren't uploaded and thus known on Cloud Build.
>
> For
> this, you have to run your Cloud Build job at the parent directory
> level, and reference the CloudBuild.yaml file in your command (and
> point to the correct subdirectory).
>
> Think to also change your
> cloudbuild.yaml step definition, because your root folder is no longer
> the subdirectory, but the root directory. You can use the directory
> parameter to specify the working directory at each step.
>
> If you
> don't want to upload the whole monorepo on each component build, you
> can [ignore files](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--ignore-file) when you trigger the gcloud builds summit
> command manually.
>
> However you can't do this with the triggers. You can
> ignore files but this time, it means that files have to be ignored in
> the build jobs trigger condition (for example, the readme file, when
> you push it, it's useless to trigger a new build). But, if the build
> is triggered by other files, these 'ignored files' will still be
> present in the run job.

For more information related to dependencies you can refer to the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs).
Try to upgrade the node version and deploy your cloud function using the npm latest version.

Comment: @joana Posted an answer, is it helpful?